# Error in require when deploying with capistrano-node-deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, deployment, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy my node.js app using [capistrano-node-deploy](https://github.com/loopj/capistrano-node-deploy). When running `cap deploy` I get the following error:

```
    $ cap deploy
    /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require': no such file to load -- capistrano/node-deploy (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require'
    from Capfile:1:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `load_recipes'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `load_recipes'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:31:in `execute!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
    from /usr/bin/cap:4
```

My `Gemfile` looks like this

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'capistrano', '~> 2.15.5'
gem 'capistrano-node-deploy', '~> 1.2.11'
gem 'capistrano_rsync_with_remote_cache', '~> 2.4.0'
gem 'capistrano-shared_file', '~> 0.1.3'
```

I then did a `bundle install` which appeared to be successful:

```
$ bundle install
Using highline (1.6.20)
Using net-ssh (2.7.0)
Using net-scp (1.1.2)
Using net-sftp (2.1.2)
Using net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
Using capistrano (2.15.5)
Using multi_json (1.3.7)
Using railsless-deploy (1.1.2)
Using capistrano-node-deploy (1.2.11)
Using capistrano-shared_file (0.1.3)
Using capistrano_rsync_with_remote_cache (2.4.0)
Using bundler (1.3.5)
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

I then created a `Capfile` which follows, based on [this blog post](https://usu.li/deploying-a-ghost-blog-using-capistrano/)

```
require "capistrano/node-deploy"
require "capistrano/shared_file"

set :application, "tff"
set :user, "ubuntu"
set :deploy_to, "/home/ubuntu/www/tff"

set :node_user, "ubuntu"
set :node_env, "production"

set :scm, :git
set :repository,  "/home/ubuntu/tff/tff.git"
set :deploy_via, :rsync_with_remote_cache

role :app, "example.org"

set :shared_files,    ["config.js"]
set :shared_children, ["content/data", "content/images"]

set :keep_releases, 5

namespace :deploy do
  task :mkdir_shared do
    run "cd #{shared_path} && mkdir -p data images files"
  end
end

after "deploy:create_symlink", "deploy:mkdir_shared"
```

Even a more basic setup results in the same error for me, i.e. being unable to `require "capistrano/node-deploy"`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> echo $GEM_PATH

if empty , else Try:

> sudo find / -type d -name capistrano-node-deploy*

return :

/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-node-deploy-1.2.11

> echo "export GEM_PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/" >> ~/.bashrc
>
> source ~/.bashrc
>
> echo $GEM_PATH

return: /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/

Comment: I seem to have fixed it by doing a few more `require`s in the Gemfile.My `$GEM_PATH` is empty though, should I set it too?

Comment: This is not the best solution, therefore, without the need not worth.